# Intel HAXM installation Failed

Tags: android, intel, osx-elcapitan

I installed HAXM using Android SDK and it gave me an error of `Not Installed` while building. On maual installation, I get the following error. Can anyone help to figure out this?

```
Last login: Sun Jul 19 21:44:03 on ttys000
Tikas-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ /Users/user/Downloads/haxm-macosx_r05/HAXM\ installation ; exit;
2015-07-19 21:56:46.472 HAXM installation[779:65674] AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges failed with return: -60031
2015-07-19 21:56:46.472 HAXM installation[779:65674] HAXM installation failed!
logout
Saving session...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x

Comment: Maybe this can help you

Comment: @DominicD'Souza, does not help. I get error: `/Users/tika/Library/Android/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/com.intel.kext.intelhaxm failed to load - (libkern/kext) not found; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).`

Comment: what is the processor on ur mac?

Comment: AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges() was deprecated in OS X 10.7 but seems to still pop up if you're using FileVault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: This answer is obsolete. Use [adamvert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32205421/199364).

---

For anyone coming here, Preview Versions of Max OS X like `El Capitan` do not completely support all apps like the `HAXM`

Downgraded to `Yosemite` and it worked.

Comment: FYI: This answer is obsolete. Use [adamvert's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32205421/199364).

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into this problem as well. I'm running `Yosemite` so the downgrading solution isn't pertinent. Eventually I decided to try running the `silent_install.sh` that's in the same dir as `HAXM installation`, and it worked.

---

**Details**

1. Open terminal window. (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal)
2. sudo ~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/silent_install.sh
3. when prompted, enter sudo password.
4. wait a minute - says "Silent installation Pass!".

To verify success:

1. Open Google Android Virtual Device (AVD) manager.
2. Create a virtual machine with x86 or x86_64 as architecture.
3. Start that virtual machine - says "HAX is enabled", and Android Emulator window opens showing the emulated device.

Comment: This got me in the right direction, but I had to manually download the latest HAXM directly from the intel repo found here: https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases. I then had to make it executable `sudo chmod +x ~/Downloads/silent_install.sh` before executing it with terminal.

Comment: In zsh terminal: "sudo bash silent_install.sh" to start the installation.

Answer (score 0):

if the reason is that you upgraded to High Sierra 10.13 masOS
then : Do this on your own responsibility as I am not sure that it has no side effects

Download the HAXM-maxosx_v6_2_1

open the file silent_install.sh

go to the line :

```
for v in 10.8 10.9 10.10 10.11 10.12
```

add to it 10.13 if your os is High Sierra  10.13.xx

so it will be :

```
for v in 10.8 10.9 10.10 10.11 10.12 10.13
```

then run the silent_install.sh file as sudo

then it will pass :)